# Is it possible to change a tweet's timestamp after tweeting?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to change a tweet's timestamp (via web-UI or API) after you've created ("tweeted") a tweet? Is the timestamping out of the user's reach?

I am looking for "one way web apps", Internet applications that allow you to post, but not to change what you've posted afterwards. I think Twitter is one of these web apps. It only offers delete, but not to modify tweets, once published.

I am asking in relation to researching "[digital forgetting](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2009/12/features/25-ideas-for-2010-digital-forgetting)", so I am open for more suggestions of similar one way apps.

To clarify my purpose:

The idea of having "one way web apps" is similar to the idea of the bitcoin ["block chain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_chain_%28database%29), where each new block contains a hash of the previous block, so you can't change what's in a chain's "tail" when a new "head" is added. And then, it's also public, so everyone is watching the integrity of the chain. I think it's also called forward hashing, a principle found in modern [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control). That's why the bitcoin block chain is sometimes used to store non-bitcoin related hashes and this way providing proof of a certain hash at a certain point in time. A bit like buying today's newspaper and taking a photograph of it with something else.

Twitter, as it's immutable (discussed here) is similar, although the company "guarantees" for the integrity, with a closed sort-of forward hashing system, as they don't allow users to alter tweets - but then the public is watching which levels this.

Comment: I genuinely doubt it—the timestamp of a tweet is at the core of the entire service, but I don’t have “official” proof to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is currently not possible. There is no such feature in Twitter or any known turn arounds or hacks for that matter.

Comment: No need to be sorry: that's the answer I was hoping for in that research context. Although other users probably have a different use-case.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to edit meta-data of already tweeted tweets but the creative way to do your task is simply delete your previous tweet and tweet again at the desired time.
Hope this helps.